# Troubleshooting Persistent Error Following Parachain Runtime Upgrade Despite Code Modification

Tags: parachain, runtime-upgrade, subxt

We recently attempted a runtime upgrade on our parachain testnet (`wss://moonbeam-integration-parachain.polkadex.trade`) and made some modifications to the `validate_unsigned` code, specifically eliminating the following section: https://github.com/Polkadex-Substrate/parachain/blob/zk-upgrade/pallets/thea-message-handler/src/lib.rs#L253-L287.

However, despite the changes, we encounter the error referenced in https://github.com/Polkadex-Substrate/parachain/blob/zk-upgrade/pallets/thea-message-handler/src/lib.rs#L265 when sending usigned transaction using `subxt` client post-upgrade. Interestingly, this error should no longer exist as its associated code has been removed.

It's worth noting that we have updated the spec version in runtime, confirming that the runtime update was executed successfully.

Could you suggest what might be preventing the successful implementation of our code upgrade?

Error:-
[image]

Update:

- When we tried to send an unsigned transaction using Polkadot.js - it worked. It looks like it's happening because of subxt.

Comment: Have you tried to run your parachain build with latest code on a local environment?

Comment: Could you update your github links with permanent links ? Your second link is now pointing to a line which has a function argument instead one of the errors. Thanks!

Comment: Also would be good to know in which Block# the runtime upgraded enacted, and in which block your unsigned transaction is included.

Comment: Hey @AlejandroMartínez, I updated the link. Also at block no 55234 [https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fmoonbeam-integration-parachain.polkadex.trade#/explorer/query/0x5c7b75c6568375c8fad6af0712b5d7dae82d67401e361cbd782bc3e1783702f0] upgrade got enacted. And we sent an unsigned transaction around 55240.

Comment: I cannot find the custom Error with code `1` in your codebase, would be great if you could point to it.
The rest of logs you are observing is the node banning that concrete tx from being sent again to avoid spam, to get rid of that you will need to restart the node that has banned it.

Comment: Could you also point to the version of the code from which you compiled to do the runtime upgrade ? The one without all those checks in `validate_incoming_message`

Comment: Hey @AlejandroMartínez, check the update section. I guess Subxt is somehow not working correctly.

Comment: Interesting that with polkadotJS works, can you share the code of how are you creating the extrinsic with subxt?

Comment: "an unsigned transaction" is the exact same unsigned transaction that you were sending with subxt ? What is banned is the concrete tx - https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/73c1388d6de8fe4b56463ba793393a0b2a2f25c8/client/transaction-pool/src/graph/rotator.rs#L65

Comment: If you still think that Subxt is at fault, could you provide the Subxt code that submits the transaction, and perhaps also the corresponding Polkadot.js steps that you took so that we can compare?

Comment: Hey, I found the issue. I was providing old metadata.

Comment: @ZKT fancy adding that as a proper answer and accepting it? :)

Answer (score 0):

Would be good in the future if you could explain how you are performing runtime upgrades in subxt because there is at least two ways to do that.

However, I think you are running into https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/issues/1319 and it was a bug subxt where the metadata was updated on a "too early block". That is fixed now.